# Can you SQL populate a BigQuery table and set the table column modes in the same API call?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-bigquery

I'm using Google App Script to migrate data through BigQuery and I've run into an issue because the SQL I'm using to perform a WRITE_TRUNCATE load is causing the destination table to be recreated with column modes of NULLABLE rather than their previous mode of REQUIRED.

Attempting to change the modes to REQUIRED after the data is loaded using a metadata patch causes an error even though the columns don't contain any null values.

I considered working around the issue by dropping the table and recreating it again with the same REQUIRED modes, then loading the data using WRITE_APPEND instead of WRITE_TRUNCATE.  But this isn't possible because a user wants to have the same source and destination table in their SQL.

Does anyone know if it's possible to define a `BigQuery.Jobs.insert` request that includes the output schema information/metadata?

If it's not possible the only alternative I can see is to use my original work around of a WRITE_APPEND but add a temporary table into the process, to allow for the destination table appearing in the source SQL.  But if this can be avoid that would be nice.

**Additional Information**:

I did experiment with different ways of setting the schema information but when they didn't return an error message the schema seemed to get ignored.
I.e. this is the json I'm passing into `BigQuery.Jobs.insert`

```
jsnConfig = 
    {
    "configuration":
        {
        "query":
            {
            "destinationTable":
                {
                "projectId":"my-project",
                "datasetId":"sandbox_dataset",
                "tableId":"hello_world"
                },
            "writeDisposition":"WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            "useLegacySql":false,
            "query":"SELECT COL_A, COL_B, '1' AS COL_C, COL_TIMESTAMP, COL_REQUIRED FROM `my-project.sandbox_dataset.hello_world_2` ",
            "allowLargeResults":true,
            "schema":
            {
            "fields":
                [
                    {
                    "description":"Desc of Column A",
                    "type":"STRING",
                    "mode":"NULLABLE",
                    "name":"COL_A"
                    },
                    {
                    "description":"Desc of Column B",
                    "type":"STRING",
                    "mode":"REQUIRED",
                    "name":"COL_B"
                    },
                    {
                    "description":"Desc of Column C",
                    "type":"STRING",
                    "mode":"REPEATED",
                    "name":"COL_C"
                    },
                    {
                    "description":"Desc of Column Timestamp",
                    "type":"INTEGER",
                    "mode":"NULLABLE",
                    "name":"COL_TIMESTAMP"
                    },
                    {
                    "description":"Desc of Column Required",
                    "type":"STRING",
                    "mode":"REQUIRED",
                    "name":"COL_REQUIRED"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(jsnConfig, "my-project");
```

The result is that the new or existing hello_world table is truncated and loaded with the data specified in the query (so part of the json package is being read), but the column descriptions and modes aren't added as defined in the schema section.  They're just blank and NULLABLE in the table.

**More**

When I tested the REST request above using [Googles API page for BigQuery.Jobs.Insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) it highlighted the "schema" property in the request as invalid.  I think it appears the schema can be defined if you're loading the data from a file, i.e. `BigQuery.Jobs.Load` but it doesn't seem to support that functionality if you're putting the data in using an SQL source.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#specify-schema-manual-python

You can pass a schema object with your load job, meaning you can set fields to mode=REQUIRED

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this method but the schema information seemed to get ignored.  I'll add the details to my original post so that I display it better.

Answer (score 0):

this is the command you should use:

```
bq --location=[LOCATION] load --source_format=[FORMAT] [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] [PATH_TO_DATA_FILE] [PATH_TO_SCHEMA_FILE]
```

as @Roy answered, [this is done via load only](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#using_a_json_schema_file). Can you output the logs of this command?

Comment: Unfortunately the data is being `inserted` from a BigQuery source table rather than `loaded` from a GCS source file.  So I can't use the load command as you and Royzipuff have suggested :(

Comment: what about exporting to CSV or JSON to Cloud Storage first, then from there upload to BigQuery?

Comment: Yep I considered it but the inefficiency of adding a full output step i.e. A->C->B is very unappealing.  When I proposed it the preference was to sacrifice the modes if they can't be retained in the insert, rather than add the extra overhead.